# Position a textbox below another without any spacing

Tags: html, css

I have 2 textboxes (one above another) and I want to remove the gap inbetween both of them. I want to achieve the look of the textboxes in this
[dribble](http://dribbble.com/shots/859831-login?list=popular&offset=5)

html

```
<div id="User-Details">
    <input type="text" class="textbox-top" id="name" value="Name" />
    <input type="text" class="textbox-bottom" id="email" value="Email" />
</div>
```

css

```
#User-Details input
{
    padding: 5px;
    color: #999
}

.textbox-top{
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.textbox-bottom{
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: And we are going to have to guess what your HTML and CSS looks like? Or is this question more meant like a `caNiHAzT3Hc0D3Z` question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this, it's pretty easy

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DyYX4/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" /><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px;
}

input[type=text] {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

input[type=text]:nth-child(1) {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: `nth-child` doesn't work in IE < 9

Comment: Then add a class to the first one.

Comment: @PeeHaa it's obvious as bookcasey said, I just didn't made new classes to cut short styles

Comment: Nowhere did I say anything about adding extra classes. *ahum :first-child*

Comment: @PeeHaa he will come up with more text boxes, btw just had a strange experience, just take a look at it, why am needing `!important` here? `border-bottom: 0;` just don't work http://jsfiddle.net/DyYX4/1/

Comment: Because `input[type=text]` is more specific than `.first`. You don't need (/ want :) ) `!important` anywhere you just have to make the selector more specific with for example `input.first`.

Comment: Ya I saw that, seriously that's more specific than a class? I did that already before you answered